# Python reload, and IPython autoreload as well, is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, pyzo

I am using Python + IPython for Data Science. I made a folder that contains all the modules I wrote, organised in packages, something like

```
python_workfolder
|
|---a
|   |---__init__.py
|   |---a1.py
|   |---a2.py
|
|---b
|   |---__init__.py
|   |---b1.py
|   |---b2.py
|
|---c
|   |---__init__.py
|   |---c1.py
|   |---c2.py
|
|
|---script1.py
|---script2.py
```

At the beginning of each session I ask IPython to autoreload modules:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Now... let's say a1.py contains a class, `A1`, that I want to call from one of the scripts. In the `__init__.p` of package `a` I import the module

```
import a1
```

Then in the script I import the class I need

```
from a.a1 import A1
```

If there is some error in class A1 and I modify it, there is no way to have Python reload it without restarting the kernel.

I tried with `del a1`, `del sys.modules['a1']`, `del sys.modules['a']`. Each time it uses the old version of the class until I don't restart the kernel... anyone can give me some suggestions?

Comment: You may want to re-read the FineManual before stating that "reload doesn't work" ? The caveats and limitations are clearly explained: https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#imp.reload

Comment: I found out that `reload` works if I type the commands in the IPython shell but it does not if I run them through Pyzo (the IDE I'm using). That was the problem...

Answer (score 0):

This is funny. It seems that my problem is not due to IPython but to Pyzo (the IDE I'm using). I added a TestClass to a1:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def disp(self):
        print('AAA')
```

This is the output I get from running the commands in an IPython shell:

```
In [2]: from a.a1 import TestClass
In [3]: t=TestClass()
In [4]: t.disp()
AAA
```

Now I modify `disp` to print 'BBB'

```
In [5]: t.disp()
BBB
```

So it was actually reloaded... also because if I skip running the autoreload commands at the beginning, it prints 'AAA' again. So it's working.

Instead if I run the commands through Pyzo (create a script, select the lines and press F9 or right click on the editor tab and select 'Run file')  it doesn't get reloaded!

```
In [2]: (executing lines 1 to 3 of "testscript.py")
AAA
```

Again I modify `disp` to print 'BBB'

```
In [3]: (executing lines 1 to 3 of "testscript.py")
AAA
```

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but I had the same problem, so here is the solution I found. You have to use the module `sys` and before importing `a1` write the following `sys.modules.pop('a1')`:

```
import sys

sys.modules.pop('a1')
import a1
```

The module is then reloaded.